# Ubuntu fail to install

Tags: windows

I`m trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS as a second OS on my HP Pavilion 15 laptop.
After the grub popping up, I choose to install Ubuntu. And the purple screen with ubuntu logo and the dots coming, after that, I get a black screen with only the mouse.
IS there any way to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)